# Why is the swagger ui not showing my annotated REST methods?

Tags: java, rest, jersey, swagger

I'm having trouble configuring swagger to see my REST methods.  I'm working in Eclipse and Tomcat 7.  I have the following simple REST method/class:

```
package com.rest;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import com.wordnik.swagger.annotations.Api;
import com.wordnik.swagger.annotations.ApiOperation;

@Api( value="/", description="Say hello class")
@Path("/")
public class Hello {

    @GET
    @Path("/hello")
    @ApiOperation(value="/hello", notes="hello method")
    public String sayHello() {
        return "Hello World!";
    }
}
```

and I'm using the following web.xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:javaee="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
    <display-name>SwaggerTest</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>com.wordnik.swagger.jaxrs.json,com.rest</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.classnames</param-name>
            <param-value>
                com.wordnik.swagger.jersey.listing.ApiListingResourceJSON,
                com.wordnik.swagger.jersey.listing.JerseyApiDeclarationProvider,
                com.wordnik.swagger.jersey.listing.JerseyResourceListingProvider
            </param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>


    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>SwaggerJerseyJaxrsConfig</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.wordnik.swagger.jersey.config.JerseyJaxrsConfig</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>api.version</param-name>
            <param-value>0.0.1</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>swagger.api.basepath</param-name>
            <param-value>http://localhost:8080/api/</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

</web-app>
```

The rest service is available on http://localhost:8080/SwaggerTest/api/sayHello and presents the proper message in the browser.  The swagger spec for the service is available at http://localhost:8080/SwaggerTest/api-docs.  However, all that is returned is

```
{"apiVersion":"0.0.1","swaggerVersion":"1.2","apis":[{"path":"/","description":"Say hello class"}]}
```

What happened to the GET sayHello() method?  Or is that all it is supposed to return?

Any help will be greatly appreciate.  Thanks in advance.

David

P.S. the maven dependencies are

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        <version>2.7</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-multipart</artifactId>
        <version>2.7</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
        <version>2.7</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.wordnik</groupId>
        <artifactId>swagger-jersey2-jaxrs_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.12</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>swagger-ui</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.wordnik</groupId>
        <artifactId>swagger-servlet_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.12</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.7</version>
    </dependency>


</dependencies>
```

Comment: My \@Api and \@ApiOperation annotations have incorrect values for the 'value' attribute, but fixing this did not change things.  Changed to 'value="/"' and 'value="/sayHello"'.  Again, this does not help.

Comment: You web.xml has everything swagger-related commented out. What exactly do you expect to happen? Also, you're using an old version of swagger-core, and an odd set of dependencies. Not sure how you got to this configuration.

Comment: I updated the post to use jersey properly (I hope).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're using swagger-core 1.3 which produces Swagger 1.2 definitions. Swagger 1.2 wasn't too fond of root (/) based APIs. You can still show it if you change the `value` of `@Api` to anything other than "/". This does not affect the API itself, just how the documentation is hosted.

If you give it the `value` of "/root" for example, and then go to http://localhost:8080/SwaggerTest/api-docs/root - you'll see your exposed service.

Also, you're using an old version of both swagger-core and Swagger in general. It looks like you're trying to integrate with Jersey, so you can follow https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/wiki/Swagger-Core-Jersey-1.X-Project-Setup-1.5 as your integration guide. This produces Swagger 2.0 which doesn't have the same issue with root resources.

Answer (score 0):

I had not told jersey to examine the correct packages in swagger.  In  particular com.wordnik.swagger.jaxrs.listing, had to be added as follows:

```
<init-param>
    <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
    <param-value>com.ibm.dipo.rest,
                com.wordnik.swagger.jaxrs.listing</param-value>
</init-param>
```

I then

1. loaded the swagger dist tree (https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/tree/master/dist)  into my WebContent directory,
2. renamed it to api-docs,
3. Modified index.html to point to swagger's api-docs location:

   $(function () {
         var url = window.location.search.match(/url=([^&]+)/);

   ```
     if (url && url.length > 1) {
       url = decodeURIComponent(url[1]);
     } else {
       url = "http://petstore.swagger.io/v2/swagger.json";
       url = "../../api/BlueHound/api-docs"
     }
   ```

With these changes, my swagger doc is available at http://localhost:8080/RTSServices/api-docs/index.html

The complete web.xml follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:javaee="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
    <display-name>RTSServices</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>com.ibm.dipo.rest,
                        com.wordnik.swagger.jaxrs.listing</param-value>
        </init-param>

        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/api/BlueHound/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>SwaggerJerseyJaxrsConfig</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.wordnik.swagger.jersey.config.JerseyJaxrsConfig</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>api.version</param-name>
            <param-value>0.0.1</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>swagger.api.basepath</param-name>
            <param-value>http://localhost:8080/RTSServices/api/BlueHound/</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

</web-app>
```

Comment: And to Ron's answer, I didn't have to change any of my maven dependencies.

Comment: I think you should accept this answer (your own) as the answer to your question ...